# Eclipse not updating, something blocking connection?

Tags: eclipse

While updating software in Eclipse using menu 'install new software' , the program stops when connected to updateServer

Installing software: Fetching oracle.eclipse.runtime.glassfish_3.1.0.0.jar (3,93kB of 78,33MB at 0B/s) from ... well, I tried several and it just stops

- I tried running eclipse as administrator
- I tried without firewall
- I tried on a clean eclipse install

somehow something is blocking
what have i been missing

Answer (score 0):

This is usually linked to some kind of proxy issue, as illustrated in [bug 330877](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=330877):

> > Pick one of the default sites that came pre-installed with eclipse in the drop-down at the top of the box.
> >     Progress window says "Fetching children of Helios" (or whatever update site you're trying).
> >     It grinds for a few minutes, gets to 50% progress, then pops the error dialog.
> >     Repeat with any other update site you can think of, watch them all fail.
>
> OK - I found the issue - this is on Windows XP, and the IE network
>   configuration had a hard proxy setting that was throwing Helios off.
>   The weird part is that this didn't seem to affect Ganymede or most of my other apps.